# Dart : Compare between different type of list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, compare, difference

I have two type of list.
Here,

```
List list1= [
  {"id": "3", "topic_name": "Studying In Bangladesh"},
  {"id": "4", "topic_name": "Studying In Sweden"},
  {"id": "6", "topic_name": "Studying In Germany"},
];

List list2 = [
  "2",
  "3",
  "5",
  "6",
];
```

I want to generate a new topic list from list1,  which is matched by list2's elements *( with list1's id )*.

Is there any method are available for dart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
List list3 = list1.where((e) => list2.contains(e['id'])).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare list1's id element with the list 2 with the foreach property in list for iterate through all elements of the list